# Would "percentage of correct answers" be considered interval or ratio data?

Tags: continuous-data, scales, percentage, variable

I'm currently working on a research assignment an I'm trying to determine whether a dependent variable like "percentage of correct answers" would be considered interval or ratio data. I was originally thinking ratio because it does seem like there would be a true zero (i.e. getting 0% correct), but I keep finding mixed results online. Plus, I know percentages can be tricky in this sort of situation. Any advice?

Comment: Arguably, either the answer doesn't matter or it depends on contingencies like how many answers there are *in toto* and the purpose of your analysis.  That would explain why online researches do not produce a consistent answer.  For instance, if there are only two questions then the possible values of the variable are 0, 50, and 100: in many circumstances it would be more fruitful to analyze that as a nominal variable and treating it as ratio or interval might obscure, rather than reveal, useful information.

Answer (score -1):

All percentages are ratios: the percentage of correct answers is the ratio of correct answers to total answers.

Comment: This is not the sense in which the question intends "ratio" to be understood.